# Using WebAPI In Another MVC Project Getting Error Is The origin 'http://localhost:3038' is not allowed

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I Have Created A WebAPI In MVC That Code Is Working Fine Am Trying To Use That Get Method In Another Project Of MVC With JQuery Function Call When Am Calling The Method Am Getting The Error is

**The origin 'http://localhost:3038' is not allowed**

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:63540/api/emp",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
            $("#tbDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].E_id + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].E_name + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Designation + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].DepartmentName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].E_doj + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].EmpType + "</td></tr>");
        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
});
```

I Have Enabled cors for WebAPI in Like in 
WebApiConfig.cs file added config.EnableCors();

And In API I added

[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:63540", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

Even I Enabled CORS In API Am Getting Error,How can solve this?,
Thanks.

Comment: Dont it need to be : `[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:63540", headers: "*", methods: "*")]` ?

Comment: Okay I ll try with removing this ...

Comment: I got the solution I have added astrik instead localhost in origins but it is calling two times I am calling once only first time no data is coming for the second time the data is coming so the output is not displayed how to fix this ...

Answer (score 1):

try this: Add To in Global.asax.cs file "Application_BeginRequest" method

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
 {
     HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");// or POST, PUT and etc.. 
     HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
     HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
     HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "", methods: "")]
I have changed origins to astrik so it is working ...